# How to access values to use values from nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck I use financial API, however I can't comprehend how to get that information to render on the page. I need to get to price in the profile and vol Avg.  Please help.

That's what I use, I am able to `console log data.body` which returns the nested object.

```
data {
  symbol: 'AAPL',
  profile: {
    price: 291.45,
    beta: '1.139593',
    volAvg: '36724977',
    mktCap: '1345844630130.00',
    lastDiv: '2.92',
    range: '142-233.47',
    changes: -0.75,
    changesPercentage: '(-0.25%)',
    companyName: 'Apple Inc.',
    exchange: 'Nasdaq Global Select',
    industry: 'Computer Hardware',
    website: 'http://www.apple.com',
    description: 'Apple Inc is designs, manufactures and markets mobile communication and media devices and personal computers, and sells a variety of related software, services, accessories, networking solutions and third-party digital content and applications.',
    ceo: 'Timothy D. Cook',
    sector: 'Technology',
    image: 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/images-New-jpg/AAPL.jpg'
  }
}



 app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
   superagent.get(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/AAPL`).then(data => {       

    const companyData = data.body.map(company => new Company(company));
    // console.log(data, companyData);
    res.render('/search', { companyData });
   }).catch(error => {
   res.render('error', { error });
   });
   });
```

Comment: There is no body property on the data object that’s why you can’t use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the price with `data.profile.price` and the avgvol with `data.profile.volAvg`

Don't forget to add what it's contained in, which in this case I guess is `companyData`

`companyData.data.profile.price`